# How to map xml field to picklist field in salesforce using Dataweave

Tags: dataweave

[flow1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0UCN.png)The below snippet is the dataweave mapping, I am getting null values for zmarket. Can anyone please tell me how to map the values for the picklist field!

```
<dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
[{
 Zmarket__c : payload.Z0DEBMAS.IDOC.E1KNA1M.Zmarket,
}]]]></dw:set-payload>
```

The zmarket field is a picklist field in salesforce and below is the IDOC xml
Input xml:

```
<Z0DEBMAS>
  <IDOC>
    <E1KNA1M>
      <Zmarket>AY</Zmarket>
    </E1KNA1M>
  </IDOC>
</Z0DEBMAS>
```

Comment: Can you share exactly what your input is? Because if it has namespaces, then the above won't work. Also is the mime-type set correctly for the input? Because if Dataweave sees that as a string, then it won't parse correctly either.

Comment: Thanks for your help Chad,now the issue looks to be different,it would be great if you can help me in this. iam trying to map the idoc xml fields to salesforce using dataweave.scenario :- first iam mapping the fields using upsert operation and fetching the id from there and creating another record with that id in another object.so here two mappings are required one after another.my issue is both the mappings are not working together but individually working fine,attached the screenshot of the flow and input xml @Chad

Comment: What does "the issue looks to be different" mean? "both the mappings are not working" can you provide an error message or more details? You need to give me more information so I can help. Vague information doesn't help.